# How to make a TextView multiline programmatically in Android (Java)

Tags: java, android, textview, multiline

I want to make my textview multiline.

Image : http://s13.postimg.org/y0q78e1yv/Capture.png

But how can I make my text multiline ?

Which atribut ?

```
TextView txt_tweet = (TextView) View.inflate(this, R.layout.special_textview, null);
```

special_textview

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false">

</TextView>
```

Comment: Please do a little research before posting such questions...

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain i have the problem since three days :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15032870/create-a-multiline-edittext-programatically

i checked something like this, i think 10-20 sites but it doesn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to show to different texts in the same textview? if so, use two text views like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Remote android:inputType="textMultiLine", this is an EditText Atribute.

If you just want to use more then one line in the same text view:

```
android:maxLines="5"//optional to set max numbers of lines
android:minLines="2"//optional to set min numbers of lines
android:singleLine="false"//set false to allow multiple line
android:lines="2" //or more
```

If this textview you want to use belongs to a ListView, just use:

```
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2
```

It will give you two texts views to work on.

Comment: Thank you for your anser, i changed now all to linear layout :
http://s27.postimg.org/9mtnp5f3z/Capture.jpg?noCache=1433860180
on the picture you see 3 Rows, the first is hardcoded, and the second and third is with my code from special_textview (is the same textview like the hardcoded)

Answer (score 7):

I did it following way:

```
tv.setElegantTextHeight(true);
tv.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
tv.setSingleLine(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

First replace "`\n`" with its Html equavalent "`&lt;br&gt;`" then call `Html.fromHtml()` on the string. Follow below steps:

```
String text= model.getMessageBody().toString().replace("\n", "&lt;br&gt;")
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(Html.fromHtml(text).toString()))
```

This works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the answers: the order matters!

Make sure you call setInputType **before** setMinLines!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
txt_tweet.setSingleLine(false);
txt_tweet.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_ENTER_ACTION);
```

Answer (score 0):

The TextView must have the 'singleLine' attribute set to false. Also you should set the 'ellipsize' to wrap the text:

```
android:singleLine="false"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

Comment: now, at the end 3 Points apears, but it also on one line :(

Answer (score 0):

in layout

```
android:lines="8"  //Total Lines prior display
android:minLines="6" //Minimum lines
android:maxLines="10" //Maximum Lines
```

Answer (score -1):

Just remove this line:

```
 android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

inputType for EditTexts